# Landscape installer stalls after bootstrapping first node. SSh works from MAAS but seems to be doing nothing

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Maas: 1.9.0

Juju: 1.24.7-trusty-amd64

I imported 3 machines into maas with 2 Nics and 3 Disks each and commissioned them.  I then chose the services of openstack to deply and started the region deployment.

The first node was then powered on and bootstrapped just fine.  From the maas server I can ping it via dns (os-node.maas) and also ssh into it via IP and hostname.

It appears after the server is bootstrapped it just sits there and does nothing.